# Preserve activity on volutarily deleted questions or reactivate them (partially)?

Tags: feature-request, removal, question

This question was removed voluntarily by the author: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/253855/does-it-make-sense-to-outsource-code-refactoring?noredirect=1#comment510925_253855

I made a comment while it was online, but now I am unable to contact the author. My comment does no more show up in my activity, nor is the name of the questions's author mentioned anywhere. This renders me unable to communicate with the author, for which my comment was intended.

Why does my comment get removed too from my activities?

Besides, IMHO, this was a very good question. There should be a way to reactivate or otherwise preserve such good questions in a form the original author could agree.

Comment: as far as I [can see](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools "10K users have privilege to see deleted posts") the question has down and close vote on it. This may be a reason why asker decided to delete. If system would allow to pester askers about questions they decided to delete for reasons like that, this would be rather unfair wouldn't it?

Comment: Hm - not really IMHO. I already have considered reposting this question by myself, because I find it quite relevant these days. However I do not want to do this before contacting the OP of this question. Sadly, I can not do this anymore.

Comment: Google cache to my rescue, found it there.

Comment: well if you repost, consider cleaning up stuff like "doesn't make sense at all" if you want a better chance for it to stay open and with positive score. "avoid asking subjective questions where … your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”" ([help/dont-ask])